# Can Lipschitz function on closed interval be approximated by differentiable functions and how?

Tags: analysis

Can Lipschitz function on closed interval be approximated by differentiable functions with bounded derivative and how?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938281/how-to-approximate-a-globally-lipschitz-function-by-differentiable-functions-wit

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918610/every-k-lipschitz-function-can-be-uniformly-approximated-by-c1-functions-wi